# Wrong matching regex

Tags: python-3.x, boolean-logic, python-re

So I'm using re module to compile my regex, and my regex looks like this:

> "(^~*\w+?[ & ~*\w+?]*?$)"

So I compile it using pattern = re.compile(regex) and then I use re.findall(pattern, string) to find if the given string is matching and to give me the group if it is.

String that I'm matching is "v1 V ~v2_ V ~~v3".

I'd expect to not have a match but it says that it matches the regular expression. I suspect that \w+ matches white spaces so that it matches the whole string but I could not find in the documentation that is correct. What am I missing?

Here this is minimum reproductible example:

```
import re

test_string = "v1 V ~v2_ V ~~v3"
regex = "(^~*\w+?[ & ~*\w+?]*?$)"

pattern = re.compile(regex)
for elem in re.findall(regex, test_string):
    print(elem)
```

Comment: Thanks for your well written question and reproducible example! What would you expect this regex to match?

Comment: This interface can maybe help you https://frama.link/Sq2tuwY-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect to not match I think your problem is with `[ & ~*\w+?]*` part.
The characters between square brackets means one occurrence of, in this case one occurrence of &, ~, *, ?, `word` and `space`. And the asterisk (`*`) at the end makes zero or many occurrences of what is in the brackets.

If what you wanted is to match this sub-regex `& ~*\w+?` zero or more times use parenthesis.

So I would say that you wanted this regex: `(^~*\w+?( & ~*\w+?)*?$)` (just change brackets for parenthesis.